# Iterate effectively across relevant neighboring pixels according to kernel/ mask

Tags: c++, opencv, filter, pixel

I have a matrix of pixels and a customized filter that uses neighbors according to specific kernel, which is given as a parameter, as well as the kernel radius. (say - cross \ square kernels, etc.)
Currently this is done by iterating through the pixels, and for each pixel go over the full radius and ask for each pixel whether it is in the kernel.
partial code snippet:

```
for (uint32_t y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (uint32_t x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        // Compute bottom and top according to kernel radius and borders
        for (uint32_t wy = bottom; wy <= top; ++wy)
            {
                int ny = wy - y;
                for (uint32_t wx = left; wx <= right; ++wx)
                {
                    int nx = wx - x;
                    if (selectedKernel.at<unsigned char>(cv::Point(nx + halfWinX,
                                                                    ny + halfWinY)) == 0)
                    {
                        continue;  // Current pixel not in kernel, nothing to do
                    }
                    // Do the actual processing
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Obviously this is not very efficient due to the high cost of the branching.
What could be more efficient (and preferably elegant), yet general (and not kernel-type specific) implementation for this?

Thanks.

Comment: in traditional filtering, the only method I know is to separate the filter (if applicable). In general you want to read the pixel values as seldom as possible, so try to cache a pixel value for the whole neighborhood it is included in (so it is read only once for the whole neighborhood). Maybe you find some techniques in efficient non-maximum suppression, but not sure.

Comment: If you are doing normal convolution, you do not have to branch. Just add 0*pixel, because e.g. 1*a + 3*c == 1*a + 0*b + 3*c. ;) Additionally you can also make the kernel size known at compile time, so the compiler can unroll the inner loop(s).

Comment: @Dobi - thanks, you are right mathematically, but in this specific case the other calculations will cost about the same as the branching (exponent, reading pixels from several sources, etc.), so I can't use it.

Comment: Have you actually measured the time both versions take in release mode (i.e. with optimizations)? Also with loop unrolling (known kernel size at compile time)?

Comment: @Dobi - yes, I measured. The computations are heavier than the branching, even when the loop is unrolled (Since I wasn't sure that the compiler actually unrolls the loop I tried to unroll it by code. Still didn't outperform). Anyway this is nice idea - I didn't think of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing simple convolution, you can simply put the filter mask in a Mat and pass the image and mask to the function [filter2d](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=filter2d#filter2d) as explained [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html). For this the mask does not need to be separable.

If you're doing correlation instead of convolution you have to flip your mask along both axis and then apply filter2d.

If you want to perform non-linear filtering, your best way is to derive your own filter from the [BaseFilter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#basefilter) class. Since I haven't done this myself yet, I cannot give you any more hints on how to do this.

The reason why I point to OpenCV functions is that they are highly optimized using SIMD instructions and TBB. You probably cannot get any faster than this. Another point is, that when using them, you don't have to think about boundaries.

Obviously those functions all assume rectangular kernels, but usually you can trick OpenCV by setting values of the kernel, that are outside of your desired shape to some special value, so that the intermediate results will not contribute to the overall result. For convolution with a disk shaped kernel those will be 0, because 0 times the image element is 0 and will not contribute to the overall sum. Although this might seem to be an unnecessary calculation, it is usually faster than doing checks, because, as you said, of branching.

Comment: Yes, OpenCVs built-in functions are faster than reinvented wheels most of the time.